# Handling button click event of dynamically loaded user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, event-handling

I am trying to handle a button click event of a dynamically loaded usercontrol from my host page. My relevant code is posted below, I think I'm on the right path but what else do I need to make this function properly? I am currently receiveing "Error binding to target method." when I try to create the usercontrol. Thanks in advance for any assistance!

**aspx**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upLeadComm" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phComm" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**aspx.cs**

```
else if (e.CommandName == "GetComm")
{
    string[] cplArg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split('§');

    UserControl ucLeadComm = (UserControl)LoadControl("Controls/Comments.ascx");

    // Set the Usercontrol Type 
    Type ucType = ucLeadComm.GetType();

    // Get access to the property 
    PropertyInfo ucPropLeadID = ucType.GetProperty("LeadID");
    PropertyInfo ucPropLeadType = ucType.GetProperty("LeadType");

    EventInfo ucEventInfo = ucType.GetEvent("BtnCommClick");
    MethodInfo ucMethInfo = ucType.GetMethod("btnComm_Click");
    Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ucEventInfo.EventHandlerType, ucType, ucMethInfo);
    ucEventInfo.AddEventHandler(ucType, handler);

    // Set the property 
    ucPropLeadID.SetValue(ucLeadComm, Convert.ToInt32(cplArg[0]), null);
    ucPropLeadType.SetValue(ucLeadComm, cplArg[1], null);

    phComm.Controls.Add(ucLeadComm);

   upLeadComm.Update();
}
```

**ascx.cs**

```
public int LeadID { get; set; }
public string LeadType { get; set; }
public event EventHandler BtnCommClick;

public void btnComm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BtnCommClick(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: I assume "Error binding to target method." comes from the reflection code in the user control?  if not, can you identify the line that causes the error?

Comment: I am receiving the error from this line: Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ucEventInfo.EventHandlerType, ucType, ucMethInfo);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am receiving the error from this line: Delegate handler =
>   Delegate.CreateDelegate(ucEventInfo.EventHandlerType, ucType,
>   ucMethInfo);

The problem is that your passing `ucType` while you should pass an instance of your UserControl, so try to do:

```
Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ucEventInfo.EventHandlerType, ucLeadComm, ucMethInfo);
```

I'm not sure that `ucLeadComm` is an istance of the UserControl because I've never used `LoadControl()`, so if it isn't use: [`Activator.CreateInstance();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx) or use `GetContructor()` and `Invoke()` it to create an instance of your object.

**EDIT 1:**

> Thanks for the responses, I now receive "Object does not match target
>   type." on the next line: ucEventInfo.AddEventHandler(ucType, handler);

Also in that line you should pass an instance of your `UserControl` instead of `ucType`.

**EDIT 2:**

> Many thanks for the assistance! The project builds and does not throw
>   any errors. However, how do I go about tying this back into a method
>   within the aspx page to actually do something when the button is
>   clicked?

If I understood in this case you should create the method in your *aspx.cs*:

```
public void btnComm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Here what you want to do in the aspx.cs
}
```

And then create another `handler` creating a `MethodInfo` tied to `btnComm_Click` contained in the *aspx.cs* and passing it to `Delegate.CreateDelegate()`:

```
MethodInfo ucMethInfo = this.GetType().GetMethod("btnComm_Click");
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I now receive "Object does not match target type." on the next line: ucEventInfo.AddEventHandler(ucType, handler);

Comment: Many thanks for the assistance! The project builds and does not throw any errors. However, how do I go about tying this back into a method within the aspx page to actually do something when the button is clicked?

Comment: Does this helped you? If it does, you could think to mark it as the answer. :)

Comment: I appreciate your help and I apologize but I still cannot get this to work. I have never worked with user controls in this manner. Can you direct me to a good how to article? I have looked but have not found anything to work??

Comment: Yes, what about: [ASP.NET User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wb1a0e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).